# how to take first value by rank or second in oracle select

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I made ranking by using `rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ? ORDER BY ? ASC)`  funtion. It is working fine. But I need to take **1st** falue if max *rnk* of particular `application_id` value is 1 otherwise **2nd** one.

**TABLE** is like this

```
  APPLICATION_ID    |  EMP_CODE   | DATE_ACTION   | ACTION_ID
----------------------------------------------------------------
    24744           |  110147     | 2016-09-13    | -1
    24746           |  162286     | 2016-09-12    |  0
```

My Select is as below:

```
SELECT APPLICATION_ID,EMP_CODE,DATE_ACTION,ACTION_ID,
           rank() OVER (PARTITION BY APPLICATION_ID
                  ORDER BY DATE_ACTION ASC) as rnk
FROM TABLE WHERE ACTION_ID = -1
```

Result is:

```
RNK  | APPLICATION_ID    |  EMP_CODE   | DATE_ACTION   | ACTION_ID
------------------------------------------------------------
1    | 53207             | 260829      | 2020-03-03    | -1
2    | 53207             | 161938      | 2020-03-03    | -1
3    | 53207             | 161938      | 2020-03-03    | -1
1    | 51372             | 163668      | 2020-03-04    | -1
1    | 52819             | 260829      | 2020-03-02    | -1
2    | 52819             | 161938      | 2020-03-02    | -1
3    | 52819             | 161938      | 2020-03-02    | -1
4    | 52819             | 161938      | 2020-03-02    | -1
```

But result should be like this:

```
RNK  | APPLICATION_ID    |  EMP_CODE   | DATE_ACTION   | ACTION_ID
------------------------------------------------------------
2    | 53207             | 161938      | 2020-03-03    | -1
1    | 51372             | 163668      | 2020-03-04    | -1
2    | 52819             | 161938      | 2020-03-02    | -1
```

Comment: updated my question. I just put my query result here.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT()` analytical function also like this:

```
SELECT t.APPLICATION_ID, t.EMP_CODE, t.DATE_ACTION, t.ACTION_ID
FROM (
  SELECT APPLICATION_ID,EMP_CODE,DATE_ACTION,ACTION_ID,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY APPLICATION_ID ORDER BY DATE_ACTION DESC) as rnk,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY APPLICATION_ID) counter
  FROM tablename WHERE ACTION_ID = -1
) t
WHERE t.rnk = CASE WHEN t.counter = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```